# Pandas dataframe: multiply row by previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe as input:

```
                       df1      
                A       B      C
20/08/17    0.0000% 0.0000% 0.0000%
21/08/17    0.0000% 0.0000% 0.0000%
22/08/17    1.0000% 1.0000% 1.0000%
23/08/17    0.0000% 0.0000% 0.0000%
24/08/17    1.9417% 0.9709% 0.9709%
25/08/17    1.8692% 0.9346% 0.9346%
```

And I am trying to get the following dataframe as output:

```
                      df2       
                A       B       C
20/08/17    0.0000% 0.0000% 0.0000%
21/08/17    0.0000% 0.0000% 0.0000%
22/08/17    1.0000% 1.0000% 1.0000%
23/08/17    1.0000% 1.0000% 1.0000%
24/08/17    2.9806% 2.0097% 2.0097%
25/08/17    4.9612% 3.0194% 3.0194%
```

where the value

```
df2['A'][1]=df2['A'][0]*(1+df1.sum(axis=1))+df1['A'][1]
```

I would like to apply this function to the whole dataframe.

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Your formula is unclear in this part: `... * (1 + df1.sum(axis=1)) + ...`. `df1.sum(axis=1)` results in a series (sum of each rows). So which row do you want to add precisely?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll try to explain better:

df2['A']['21/08/17']=df2['A']['20/08/17']*(1+df1['21/08/17'].sum(axis=1))+df1['A']['21/08/17']

I would like to apply this formula to each row of the dataframe, without looping through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as expected:

```
df2 = df.copy()
for i in range(df3.index.size):
    if not i:
        continue
    df2.iloc[i] = (df2.iloc[i - 1] * (1 + df.iloc[i].sum())) + df.iloc[i]
```

You mentioned in comment that you don't want to "loop through it", but I can't figure how to do the same without a `for` loop.
The main limitation is that you want to use data from the newly computed `df2[i - 1]` in the computation of `df2[i]`.

Without this requirement (then using existing `df[i - 1]` to compute `df2[i]`) it would give `df + df.shift().fillna(0).mul(1 + df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)`, but this does not match your formula.